# Amazon EMR Service vs EMR Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

The following image, from AWS itself, shows how an EMR cluster is configured within a private subnet. Fine.

The only communication outside the subnet is to **Amazon EMR**, is stated.

Interesting that I always use the Amazon EMR Service icon to indicate the Cluster in drawings, and others I know do also. What am I missing here? The AWS EMR Service is?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EMR service will give you the libraries and packages to start your EMR cluster.

When you create the EMR cluster, watch out the bootstrap logs. It will connect to the Amazon EMR service and get the libraries and packages to build your environment. These libraries are coming from the outside of your subnet and it is managed by AWS itself, so that is clearly located the outside of your VPC either.

Comment: So, just to be clear, as EMR is now only launched in a private subnet, EMR Service manages all things as you state, and hence no IGW is needed.

Comment: Let me be clearer: For the VPC there is no IGW needed as the diagram shows, that is access to the internet elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, my statement is bit wrong, there isn't needed igw when you deploy it on the private subnet.

Comment: I am posing a more explicit question just to be sure. Have a look in a mo. As I need to be really clear.

Comment: There is an explanation about this, where the original image posted on the AWS faq that is same with yours, *Private subnets allow you to launch AWS resources without requiring the subnet to have an attached internet gateway.*

Comment: I think it is fine, but I do not want to mess up as there are so many old AWS pages.